# iPad / jQuery.animate(scroll) issues

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-animate

I have a page that uses jQuery.animate to scroll the body/html of the document, it works fine in browsers but just won't play ball with iPad.

First it is supposed to scroll in the Y direction then X, but on an iPad it scrolls in the Y, then it jumps back to the original position before scrolling in the X direction. After the animations are complete the links that are used to navigate cease to function unless you manually scroll the page, then they will work again!

What am I doing wrong here? The page is found [here...](http://lab12.co.uk/peli/notes_stack.html)

Thanks in advance,
Phil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. iOS does not scroll the body, but it moves the viewport. This causes some undesired effects when jQuery tries to interact with it. The solution is to scroll a div instead of the body of the document.

Comment: i think I might cry! thank you so much! this works better than any of the JS lib solutions I've tried

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution!

Answer (score 2):

`scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()` aren't supported on iPad.  Try `window.pageYOffset` and `window.pageXOffset`.

Not sure what is happening with the nav links freezing until manual scroll - but its not just you - I've seen it before.

Comment: I think the functions are supported, but aren't functioning properly (as the OP said that the page animated as desired).

Comment: Blender is right - they are available but just dont work right.